# Slow Incremental Crawl Rate (dps) - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sql-server, crawl

I'm new to the whole SP world, recently started in a new role and looking at the SharePoint environment and associated hardware/SQL.

Setup is:

- 2x WFE 16GB Ram
- 2x APP Servers 16GB Ram
- 2x Search/Admin/Index 24GB Ram
- 3x SQL Cluster 40GB Ram (SQL max mem set to 34GB)

Crawl rate varies but the last couple of incrementals are only crawling around 8000 documents with a crawl rate of 1.2dps and 1700-1800ms latency.

SQL cluster is 3 node cluster with 2 active and one passive.

Everything is VMWare and hardware specs are quite high, I don't have visibility of the underlying storage.

DBs and logs have separate drives (not sure about the underlying LUNs), tempdb is on it's own drive.

One thing I do know is that the block size on the SQL drives is set to 4096 and not 65536 on all the data/log drives, again I'm not sure what the block size and raid config. of the underlying storage is set to either.

Despite all that this kit is still pretty decent and the dps rate of 1.2 is horrific.

Anyone got any thoughts? I've looked at a few things already search service performance level is set to PartlyReduced... crawl is running outside of business hours and nothing else should be hitting the box at that time.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There are many things to check.

- Many of times, i noticed that it is because of AntiVirus which cause this issue. You should make sure the You exclude the certain folder from the AV scanning.[Check this kb](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/952167)
- Check the system resources when you run the crawl.
- Check the Database perfromance on the DB servers.

Here are some tips from MSDN blogs.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kristopherloranger/2013/05/30/sharepoint-2013-crawler-troubleshooting-concepts/